# Google Sheets time sorting chart

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts, google-sheets-dates

I have a MailChimp data export in google sheets and I want to create some charts that can show the best time of day/day of the week based on my data for our mail outs when compared to open rate (%). I have all the days and all the exact times but can't for the life of me find a way of setting up an axis for 24 hours and plotting the percentage of opens placed in the 24hour period to compare, or have the 7 days of the week and have the bars located with the highest average opens for each day, etc.. Is this possible?

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community User 14 times. The OP replied to a comment providing a link to a spreadsheet, but the spreadsheet is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

- select column **B:C**
- **Insert** > **Chart**
- tick **Agregate** for x-axis

  [image: 0]

Comment: Not all the questions should be answered. Ref. [answer]. The resolution of a recent discussion about the site "research policy" mentioned that Web Applications is not a help desk. [Referred Meta discussion](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/88163)